# Ionic swiper does not work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am new in using ionic framework and I faced with follow problem.
I added swiper in my template.

```
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div ng-controller="CarouselController">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="i in new_issues"><img ng-src="{{ i.image }}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And then define it inside controller.

```
.controller('CarouselController', function($scope) {

    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        speed: 400,
        spaceBetween: 100,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        centeredSlides: true
    }); 

})
```

And  this slider does not work right after page was loaded. To make it working I have to click to the top button witch just show me some pop up window and only after closing that window my slider start working.
Here you can see how it work http://mobile.pressa.ru.
Could somebody help me?

Comment: Also when I resize my browser`s window  carousel begins working well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-create-elegant-slider-carousel-in-ionic-framework/
I created such directive

```
.directive('imageonload', function($rootScope) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
element.bind('load', function() {
$rootScope.swiper.updateSlidesSize();
});
}
};
})
```

and added it to img tag

```
<img imageonload="" ng-src="{{ i.image }}">
```

Previously defining it in my $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're not using the swiper as a directive, and thus not integrating the `$scope` digest binding (as @zdimon77 hints).

Try this (assuming you're using Ionic 1.2):

**HTML**

```
<ion-slides options="sliderOptions" slider="data.slider">
  <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="(i, issue) in new_issues">
    <img ng-src="{{ issue.image }}" />
  </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

and in your **AngularJS controller**:

```
.controller('CarouselController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sliderOptions = {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true
  };

  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.$watch('data.slider',function(slider){
      console.log('My slider object is ', slider);
      // Your custom logic here
  });
});
```

I referenced [this tutorial](http://%20%20//http://www.ghadeerrahhal.com/ionic-vertical-slidebox/).